# Error: [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement] PreparedStatement.close() called: java.lang.Throwable: PreparedStatement.close() called

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, jboss7.x

Following error occurring when my application accessed by around 200 users. 
JBoss Version AS 7.1.1,
SQL Server 2012

```
2016-08-29 23:33:08,309 TRACE [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement] PreparedStatement.close() called: java.lang.Throwable: PreparedStatement.close() called
  at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1589)
  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.closePreparedStatement(CachedPreparedStatement.java:452)
  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.agedOut(CachedPreparedStatement.java:467)
  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.PreparedStatementCache.onEviction(PreparedStatementCache.java:224)
  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.PreparedStatementCache.onEviction(PreparedStatementCache.java:41)
  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.util.LRUCache.ageOut(LRUCache.java:190)
  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.util.LRUCache.access$700(LRUCache.java:37)
  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.util.LRUCache$LRUList.demote(LRUCache.java:356)
  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.util.LRUCache.insert(LRUCache.java:132)
  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.PreparedStatementCache.put(PreparedStatementCache.java:203)
  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:715)
  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:405)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:225)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:497)
  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:415)
  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1538)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:661)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
  at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:375)
  at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
  at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
  at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
  at com.codeobjects.cov3.ordermgmt.renewal.assignment.services.impl.PartyServiceImpl.queryExpressionPrivate(PartyServiceImpl.java:518)
  at com.codeobjects.cov3.ordermgmt.renewal.assignment.services.impl.PartyServiceImpl.queryPrivate(PartyServiceImpl.java:554)
  at com.codeobjects.cov3.ordermgmt.renewal.assignment.services.impl.PartyServiceImpl.query(PartyServiceImpl.java:197)
  at com.codeobjects.cov3.ordermgmt.renewal.assignment.services.impl.PartyServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$970d82c8.invoke(<generated>)
  at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
  at com.codeobjects.cov3.ordermgmt.renewal.assignment.services.impl.PartyServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3002773d.query(<generated>)
  at com.codeobjects.fa.common.webservice.services.impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl.validateParty(UserRegistrationServiceImpl.java:226)
  at com.codeobjects.fa.common.webservice.services.impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl.registerUser(UserRegistrationServiceImpl.java:277)
  at com.codeobjects.fa.re.ho.webservice.services.impl.ConsumerRegistrationActionsServiceImpl.createLogin(ConsumerRegistrationActionsServiceImpl.java:473)
  at com.codeobjects.fa.re.ho.webservice.services.impl.ConsumerRegistrationActionsServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d7f03c07.invoke(<generated>)
  at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
  at com.codeobjects.fa.re.ho.webservice.services.impl.ConsumerRegistrationActionsServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3ce494a1.createLogin(<generated>)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor328.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.createLogin(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor328.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:54)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.service.binding.ServiceInvocationHandler.sendMessage(ServiceInvocationHandler.java:322)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.service.binding.ServiceInvocationHandler$1.run(ServiceInvocationHandler.java:86)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.service.binding.ServiceInvocationHandler.execute(ServiceInvocationHandler.java:134)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.service.binding.ServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(ServiceInvocationHandler.java:109)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline.invoke(HandlerPipeline.java:131)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.DefaultEndpoint.onReceive(DefaultEndpoint.java:64)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.AbstractChannel.receive(AbstractChannel.java:38)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireServletController.invoke(XFireServletController.java:304)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireServletController.doService(XFireServletController.java:129)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.spring.remoting.XFireServletControllerAdapter.handleRequest(XFireServletControllerAdapter.java:67)
  at org.codehaus.xfire.spring.remoting.XFireExporter.handleRequest(XFireExporter.java:48)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
  at com.codeobjects.platform.services.runtime.spring.web.servlet.CODispatcherServlet.service(CODispatcherServlet.java:41)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:359)
  at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
  at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
  at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
  at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
  at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
  at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
  at com.codeobjects.platform.services.runtime.security.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:103)
  at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
  at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
  at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
  at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
  at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:174)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
  at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:91)
  at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:72)
  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

JBoss AS 7.1.1

SQL Server 2012

Please let me know if someone need more information.

The current configuration is as follows.

```
  <driver>mssql</driver>
                        <xa-pool>
                            <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                            <prefill>true</prefill>
                        </xa-pool>
                        <validation>
                            <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        </validation>
                        <statement>
                            <prepared-statement-cache-size>128</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                            <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                        </statement>
                    </xa-datasource>
                    <drivers>
```

Answer (score 0):

use connection pooling for this.reconfigure standalone.xml and define data source,jndi name and other DB configuration in this file.

Comment: Can you please specify your answer by suggesting exactly what all parameters I have to change? I have added current configuration above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check following link may be it would be helpful for you.http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/how-to-configure-a-datasource-with-jboss-7